# Numbervalue's value not being updated in script

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a variable which holds the information of a numbervalue but when I put the variable in my script it only returns the first value of the numbervalue. So when the numbervalue is modified by a different script, it doesn't change in this script. This means it always returns 0. I want the variable holding the numbervalue in my script to constantly update it's value.

```
local value = game.Workspace:WaitForChild(player.Name.. "1"):WaitForChild("MyNumberValue")
```

this is the variable. The numbervalue is created for each separate player when they join as a child of a folder which is named after the player. This is why I used waitforchild. Everything is referenced correctly, and there are no errors or typo's (that I can see) or issues the script hierachy. I used print(value) and it returned MyNumberValue, which shows that it is all referenced correctly.

The numbervalue holds information for each players pet equipped power. (so it constantly changes) The script itself is a child of a magnet (tool)

This is my whole script:

```
local tool = script.Parent
local equiped = false
local handle = tool:WaitForChild("Handle",20)
local deb = false
local value
local newvalue

tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    equiped = true
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(tool.Parent)
    local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    repeat wait()
        local raio = tool:WaitForChild("Range",20).Value
        local Moedas = {}
        local Valores = {}
        local root = tool:FindFirstChild("Handle")
        if not root then return end
        for i,v in pairs(workspace:WaitForChild("Coins",20):GetChildren())do
            for a,b in pairs(v:GetChildren())do
                if b:IsA("BasePart") and (raio > (root.Position-b.Position).Magnitude) then
                    if b and b:FindFirstChild("Attachment") and v:FindFirstChild("Valor") and not b:FindFirstChild("Beam") then
                        local beam = Instance.new("Beam")
                        beam.Name = "Beam"
                        beam.CurveSize0 = 1
                        beam.CurveSize1 = 1
                        beam.FaceCamera = true
                        beam.Color = ColorSequence.new(Color3.fromRGB(0,255,255),Color3.fromRGB(0,255,255))
                        beam.Width0 = 1
                        beam.Width1 = 1
                        beam.Transparency = NumberSequence.new(0.5)
                        beam.Attachment0 = b:WaitForChild("Attachment")
                        beam.Attachment1 = handle:WaitForChild("Attachment")
                        beam.Parent = b
                        table.insert(Moedas,a,b)
                        table.insert(Valores,a,v.Valor.Value)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        wait(.3)
        for i,v in pairs(Moedas)do
            if v and v:FindFirstChild("Beam") then
                v.Parent = nil
            end
        end
        for i,v in pairs(Valores)do
            if v and player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") and player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Coins") then
                value = game.Workspace:WaitForChild(player.Name.. "1"):WaitForChild("MyNumberValue")
                print(value)
                print(value.Parent)
                print(value.Value)
                newvalue = value.Value
                player.leaderstats.Coins.Value = player.leaderstats.Coins.Value + v + newvalue
                table.remove(Valores,i)
                print(newvalue)
            end
        end
    until equiped == false
end)

tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    equiped = false
end)
```

please help...

Comment: Also, I want the "value" variable to be added onto this line:
player.leaderstats.Coins.Value = player.leaderstats.Coins.Value + v
as the value controls the pet multiplier.

Comment: [Don't use `game.Workspace:WaitForChild(player.Name)`, it's ambiguous, use the getter](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/playercharacter-or-workspacewaitforchildplayername/809989) When you say "it breaks", do you mean the wait waits forever? If yes, first debug what of those two waits do that.

Comment: Oh yeah, your right. The variable was referencing my player and not my designated folder... Which caused the second waitforchild to wait forever. I fixed it by changing the name of the folder to player.Name.. "1". Now the script works, but value.Value always returns 0 even when the numbervalue is not 0.

Comment: I have found out that the numbervalue is returning it's first value. (its value before it is changed by the petmultiplier) meaning the numbervalue isn't being updated in my script. I have tried countless ways to update it but it just does not work. pls help

Comment: Well, where do you even update that value? Are you sure its on the same side/synced correctly?

Comment: Oh yeah, I realized that client modifications of the numberValue would not be updated serverside. I tried a different method to retrieve the player pet multiplier and it worked. :)